# How can I return a parameter after using a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter, button

How can I return a parameter after using a button in tkinter?

```
def read(excelfile):
data = pd.ExcelFile("rsc/" + excelfile + ".xlsx")
file = pd.read_excel(data)
return file

browse_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=lambda:read(), bg="#20bebe", fg="white", width=15, height=2)
```

It won't keep working in the function `def read()`.

Comment: You can't return from tkinter button commands

Comment: Why do you need it anyways?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter in your `lambda` function

```py
brows_btn = tk.Button(
    root, text="Browse", 
    command=lambda x:read(x), 
    bg="#20bebe", fg="white", 
    width=15, height=2)
```

Where `x` could be a defined variable before the creation of the button.
Like a parameter chose by the user, or something you defined before.
I think you can also define it directly in your lambda function with:

`lambda x=your_variable:read(x)`

If the parameter is an Entry value you can replace `x` by `your_entry.get()`

```py
brows_btn = tk.Button(
    root, text="Browse", 
    command=lambda:read(your_entry.get()), 
    bg="#20bebe", fg="white", 
    width=15, height=2)
```